# How to handle encrypted requests and answers with distant server using a certain protocol with react native and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-native

I'm working on a mobile application project using react native, the mobile app should use a distant server to get information
for example: to log in I must send an encrypted request to a distant server with the certain protocol for example :

03000F10081B367ACF10500019601010200
0300- Command
OF10 - Data length
081B367A -Time
etc...

the answer also will be like that and I have also to encrypt and decrypt all

So my question is how can I handle that? are there any techniques or libraries to easily do it? and should I use an API in my app?
can I program the encrypt and decrypt functions in javascript and integrate them to post and get HTTP requests?

after the login, I must display certain information that I need to send requests to the server to obtain them the same way as the login (encrypted message, protocol, etc ...)
all functionalities should be like already mentioned (connection status, battery level ....)